# GURPS supplement for Poul Anderson's "High Crusade"?

Tags: product-identification, campaign-settings, gurps, traveller, science-fiction

Recently I've been re-reading the amusing **novel "The High Crusade" by Poul Anderson** and enjoyed it as much as I did back then.

As I was reading, a thought came to my mind: I seemed to remember there was  a GURPS supplement detailing this setting and was determined to find it.
So I searched the web for it but all I was able to dig out was [this board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6917/high-crusade) (whose cover, I'll acknowledge, rings a bell), which cites Traveller, not GURPS.

So I wonder: **was there a High Crusade GURPS supplement like I seem to remember or am I completely wrong?**
And, if there was any, would you please link me to a review?
I would appreciate that a lot.

Comment: A quick inquiry to the bingleduck doesn't find any, though I'd not be surprised to find a fanac module that draws on High-Tech, Low-Tech, Space, _et cetera_, to let you play it out...

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin - My "memories" were for an official or semi-official product, not a fan-made module: but at this point I wouldn't be surprised if I were just misremembering.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The bingleduck?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Portmanteau of Bing, Google, and Duck Duck Go. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: @HeyICanChan - nick012000 got it right; I started using that as a replacement for "whatever search engine you prefer" when I started getting "ew" comments for referring only to Google or only to Bing. It doesn't get capitalized because there isn't (yet) a {meta}search engine called "Bingleduck".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there was never an official GURPS supplement for it. Steve Jackson Games' [web page](http://www.sjgames.com/ourgames/everything.html) listing everything they've ever published has no obvious mention of it.

There is a ***GURPS Crusades*** historical supplement, and there were 3e supplements for various licensed properties, such as Alan Dean Foster's *Humanx* setting.

A text search on my 8.2GB collection of GURPS and related PDFs doesn't find any mention of a High Crusade GURPS supplement although there are plenty of mentions of other works by Poul Anderson, and a couple of the High Crusade boardgame the OP found. This collection is close to complete on 3e and 4e books and PDFs, and has all of *Pyramid* volumes 1, 2, 3 and 4. It also has the currently PDF'ed issues of *Space Gamer* and *Fantasy Gamer*.

Answer (score 2):

As [John Dallman writes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/182138/78212), I don't think there's an official supplement. However, [GURPS Space: Unnight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unnight) exists, which is a setting where a lost colony has regressed to the Dark Ages:

> [H]umans from Earth travelled on faster than light ships to settle another star system. However, their ships missed the targeted system and ended up at a planet deep within a nebula. In the years that followed, without further contact from Earth, the settlers' technology gradually expired, and the planetary society broke down into feudal states.

The inhabitants are utterly unprepared for the arrival of explorers from Earth and, as this is GURPS, the book explores both playing "space invaders" as well as playing "natives".

While not an adaptation of the Poul Anderson story, I believe many concepts could seem quite similar, some 30+ years later, and could certainly have played quite similarly.